# How to modify regrex expression to deal with whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, string

```
import re
def addMultiplication(input1): 
    return re.sub(r'([^-+*/])\(', r'\1*(', input1)
```

I have a function that will take an string and add multiplication symbols whenever there are parenthesis symbolizing multiplication.

Some examples here (that work):

- "4(3)" -> "4*(3)"
- "(4)(3)" -> "(4)*(3)"
- "4*2 + 9 -4(-3)" - > "4*2 + 9 -4*(-3)"
- "(-9)(-2)   (4)" -> "(-9)*(2) *(4)"
- "4^(3)" -> "4^(3)"
- "(4-3)(4+2)" -> "(4-3)*(4+2)"
- "(Aflkdsjalkb)(g)" -> "(Aflkdsjalkb)*(g)"
- "g(d)(f)" -> "g*(d)*(f)"
- "(4) (3)" -> "(4)*(3)"

Here are some examples I am failing (because of added whitespace) the arrow points to my code's output **the farthest right and in bold** is what I want:

- "(4)* (3)" -> "(4) * * (3)" **| "(4)*(3)"**
- "(4-3* (2)" -> "4-3* *(2)"   **| 4-3 * (2)"**

Note I had to add some extra spaces in the two above examples because otherwise it kept italicizing and formatting. So basically if I get rid of the white space in my above two examples, it works, but when I leave a whitespace after the asterisk, it malfunctions.

How would I incorporate the extra whitespace in my regrex expression? I tried using `\s` but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: `\s*` is 0 or more white space characters, so it will cover tabs and spaces. Put that wherever you might need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at this is that you want to put a `*` between any character, digit or closing parenthesis (`)`) which is followed by an opening parenthesis (`(`), or any closing parenthesis which is followed by a character, digit or opening parenthesis; with some number of spaces in the middle. You can use lookaheads for that purpose, capturing the initial character/digit/parenthesis in group 1:

```
([a-z0-9)](?= *\()|\)(?= *[a-z0-9(]))
```

You can then replace this with `\1*`. Note you should use the `re.IGNORECASE` (case-insensitive, also `re.I`) flag so that it works for expression such as A(B).

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/t5Kokf/2)

In python:

```
def addMultiplication(input1): 
    return re.sub(r'([a-z0-9)](?= *\()|\)(?= *[a-z0-9(]))', r'\1*', input1, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Hey I have a small problem, when i run some special cases "2 () 9 " it's outputting "2* ()* 9" Which isn't what I want. How can I make it return "None" for these special cases.

Comment: @Iambadatpython you would need to add an `if` test to see if the expression matched those special cases and if so return `None`, otherwise do the replace. Something like `if re.search(r'\(\s*\)', input1): return None`. Without seeing all your special cases I can't do better than that; it might be worth asking a new question if there are a lot of them. You can refer back to this one as a starting point.